# c++: string.replace inserting too many characters

Tags: c++, string, vector, replace

I'm trying to step through a given string with a for loop, replacing one character per iteration with a character from a vector[char].
Problem is that the replace inserts the entire vector-k instead of the character at place k and I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

Any and all help is appreciated.

(alphabet is a const string a-z, FirstWord is the given string).

```
vector<char> VectorAlphabet;
for (int i=0; i<alphabet.length(); ++i)
{
    VectorAlphabet.push_back(alphabet.at(i));
}

        for (int i = 0; i < FirstWord.length(); ++i )
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < VectorAlphabet.size(); ++k)
            {
                string TempWord = FirstWord;
                TempWord.replace(i, 1, &VectorAlphabet[k]);
                if (CheckForValidWord(TempWord, WordSet))
                {
                    if(CheckForDuplicateChain(TempWord, DuplicateWordSet))
                    {
                        DuplicateWordSet.insert(TempWord);
                        stack<string> TempStack = WordStack;
                        TempStack.push(TempWord);
                        WordQueue.push(TempStack);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

e.g TempWord = tempword, then after TempWord.replace() on the first iteration it is abcde...zempWord. and not aempword. On the second to last iteration of the second for loop it is yzempword.

What have I missed?

Comment: `&VectorAlphabet[k]`  might be no zero terminated c-string (you are replacing one character by a c-string)

Comment: But I don't understand why i'd insert an entire string, as each position in VectorAlphabet is a char and I'm only inserting data from one position.

Comment: Try `TempWord.replace(i, 1, 1, VectorAlphabet[k]);`

Comment: That worked, thanks! I guess I need to go back and read the documentation for string.replace. Dieter - If you want, create a reply and I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, thanks to Dieter Lücking.

Looking closer at the [string.replace reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/), I see that I tried to use a replace which takes strings as the input, and then the vector[char] is interpreted as a c-string, starting from the k-position.

By using the fill-version of replace the vector position is correctly used as a char instead.

New code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FirstWord.length(); ++i )
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < VectorAlphabet.size(); ++k)
            {
                string TempWord = WordStack.top();
                // Change:
                TempWord.replace(i, 1, 1, VectorAlphabet[k]);
                if (CheckForValidWord(TempWord, WordSet))
                {
                    if(CheckForDuplicateChain(TempWord, DuplicateWordSet))
                    {
                        DuplicateWordSet.insert(TempWord);
                        stack<string> TempStack = WordStack;
                        TempStack.push(TempWord);
                        WordQueue.push(TempStack);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```